# using optimize function with iterative calculation in r

Tags: r

```r
put <- function(px) {
mgta <- 0.01 
volT_a <- .17 
s <- 500 
k <- 600 
r <- .05 
NAV <- s - px 
d1a <- NAV/k-1 + (r - mgt_a) + 5 * volT_a 
d2a <- NAV/k-1 - (r - mgt_a) + 5 * volT_a 
px <- (NAV * d1a - k * d2a) 
} 

print(optimize(function(px) (put(px) - px)^2, c(0, 0.0000000000000001)))
```

I am trying to get optimize to calculate the value of `px`, which should be `263.882353`, but I am getting another value.

Comment: The code uses mgta in one place and mgt_a in another but even if we fix that put(263.882353) - 263.882353 does not give 0 whereas the solution to the code does so  263.882353 is not the correct answer or if it is supposed to be then the code is wrong.

Comment: mgta <- 0.01 should be mgt_a <- 0.01, yes.

We are trying to solve for px... is there some way to rearrange this to make optimize work here?

Comment: It does work but the solution is not the one claimed or else your code is wrong but we have no idea what the actual problem is if that is the case.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to share a spreadsheet with you to show you how this calculation is done in Excel? I'm trying to get r to do it, but can't figure it out.

Comment: Maybe someone else will be willing to dig into it given more extensive information.

Comment: Maybe if we change the last line of code to p <- px - (NAV * d1a - k * d2a)

Now we need to set p = 0 by finding px iteratively. Does that help?